# JavaScript Regex replace if more than n occurence

Tags: javascript, regex, slug

I have a Regex which replaces all non-alphanumeric characters with a hyphen.

```
slugName = $(this).val().replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi, '-');
```

This works as it should, however since this is generated from user input, I may end up with a result like `my-awesome-title---stuff` which could have been entered as `my awesome title & stuff`

As you can see, I now have three consecutive hyphens which don't really appeal as a pretty URL.

Is there some way that I can replace such occurrences if there is a consecutive line of hyphens?

Comment: Would you also like to trim hyphens from the edges? `-still-not-pretty-`

Comment: Good source to learn regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this:

```
slugName = $(this).val().replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/gi, '-');
```

Should replace one or more instance of characters which are non-alphanumeric with 1 hyphen. The '+' in this case means one or more instance of.

Comment: Just for an extra point, how can I stop this from happening on the first and last characters?

Answer (score 2):

Use another regular expression to collapse multiple dashes:

```
slugName = slugName.replace(/-+/g, '-');
```

Comment: There is no needs in the additional `replace`, simply add `+` after cahr class definition: `[^a-z0-9]+`

Comment: All too true, +1 for npinti's answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Add `+` to char class:

```
'my awesome title & stuff'.replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/gi, '-')
```

result:

```
"my-awesome-title-stuff"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace consecutive strings of hyphens with just one

```
slugName = $(this).val().replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi, '-').replace(/[\-]+/g, '-')
```

Comment: There is no needs in the additional `replace`, simply add `+` after cahr class definition: `[^a-z0-9]+`

Comment: Seeing the others, there is no need for the extra replace, apparently we can just add a `+` which seems to stop multiples or something?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I answered quickly without thinking of the simplest solution.